Maui Shell app how to implement master/detail (FlyoutPage)?
Looking for some advice/solution. I'm converting app from Xamarin.Forms to Maui and stuck on FlyoutPage. In old app I've used Prism and FlyoutPage to setup master/detail pages for tablets, so user could swipe or tap on hamburger menu to display list of items and once tapped on item I would load details page, all worked well.
Now in Maui I don't use Prism, but switched to Shell, which works surprisingly well for our massive enterprise app. In AppShell I've Flyout enabled, like this:
<Shell
    x:Class="Happen.Mobile.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Title="App"
    x:Name="this">

Then some menu options added with MenuItemTemplate(s). So Shell Flyout is used as main menu to access extra options which don't belong to home page.
From home page I need to push master/detail page (FlyoutPage) and this is where I'm stuck. Reading Maui docs it tells that FlyoutPage is not supported by Shell, but in iOS I can push FlyoutPage without exception being thrown:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync( "TestFlyout", true, parameters );

This is how I setup FlyoutPage:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Views.TestFlyout"
             FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Default"
             IsPresented="True">

    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
                <ContentPage Title="List" IconImageSource="hamburger.png" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="This is menu"></Label>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
            <ContentPage Title="Object" IconImageSource="hamburger.png">
                <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Bisque">
                    <Label Text="This is object" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>    
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ContentPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>

And this is how it looks (notice there is not hamburger icon nor title):

Now when I close/open Flyout, both labels disappears:

So clearly something is either incompatible or broken. Question is - are we not suppose to use FlyoutPage with Shell app at all and if yes then why? Also, how else I could achieve similar master/detail functionality?

Shell and MasterDetailPage are different Navigation styles MasterDetailPagewas renamed to FlyoutPage in recent versions of XF and MAUI, so if you want a custom Flyout design you might have to use FlyoutPage instead of Shell

Thank you, but I still don't understand why in Shell you can't push another FlyoutPage? Shell itself already has built in Flyout, so what is the problem?

Would you add more coffee into the coffee maker when the coffee maker already has coffee init?

I wouldn't if coffee maker is only able to make one coffee.

Yes so you can only implement a single navigation style at a time check these for more details  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-8.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage?view=net-maui-8.0

Indeed, FlyoutPage is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps. If you use the Shell structure, you can display a list of items by setting the  tag in the AppShell.xaml file.
Depending on the FlyoutPage code you provide, you can refer to the following code for design:
<Shell ...>

    <ShellContent
        Title="Object"
        //It is recommended to place the main page of the project in a new contentpage
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ObjectPage}"
        Route="ObjectPage"/>

    <Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid  HeightRequest="200">
                   <Label Text="This is menu"></Label>
            </Grid>            
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>

</Shell>

For more details about Flyout in Shell, you can refer to .NET MAUI Shell flyout
